# What does "in a deep hole" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "in a deep hole" mean in football (soccer) context?

37 mins: Of all ways for Sevilla to concede, that has got to hurt the most. That was just so, so poor. Dortmund lead 4-2 on aggregate, and can relax and perhaps also attack a bit more. Sevilla meanwhile are in a deep hole.

Answer (score 1):

"in a deep hole" means they are at a great disadvantage because of the difference in scores. They will have to make a great effort to "climb out of the hole", that is, to get back to an even score.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the expression "in a deep hole" is a *metaphor* https://www.grammarly.com/blog/metaphor/